# Converting rows to columns using crosstab in PostgreSQL not working (relation “table” does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, view, subquery, crosstab

I need to use the compiled data using CTE and then convert the columns to rows using crosstab(open to other ideas) in the next select statement. Below is the query.

```
    with checked_adgroup AS (
         SELECT 
            ua.new_adgroup,
            ua.account,
            ua.campaign,
            ua.ad_group,
            ua."position",
            cp.category,
            pt.full_value,

   FROM unnest_adgroup ua
     LEFT JOIN taxonomy_category cp ON ua."position" = cp."position"
     LEFT JOIN taxonomy pt ON ua.short_val = pt.short_value AND cp.category = pt.category AND (pt.lob IS NULL OR pt.lob = ua.lob)
         )

        SELECT * 
        from crosstab(
        'select
        cad.account,
        cad.campaign,
        cad.ad_group,
        cad.category,
        cad.full_value
        FROM checked_adgroup cad 
        WHERE  cad.all_correct AND cad.category IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 1,2,3')
        AS final_result( 
         account text, campaign text, ad_group text,
         division text, lob text, match_type text  );
```

**Error message:
ERROR: relation "checked_adgroup" does not exist LINE 7: FROM checked_adgroup cad**

Output of checked_adgroup cte looks like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zooRF.png)

Desired output of the final statement is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4yv4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. First off please do not post images, they are useless to work with, and in some instances they are prohibited and cannot be viewed. Instead use formatted text.  
I haven't used crosstab functionality all that much, but it does offer a second version which contains 2 queries, the second feeding into the first. There are however a couple errors in your posted query that would need correcting either way. So that first. Look for --<< tag.

```
   with checked_adgroup AS (
         SELECT 
            ua.new_adgroup,
            ua.account,
            ua.campaign,
            ua.ad_group,
            ua."position",
            cp.category,
            pt.full_value,
            --<< missing column or ending , above should not be there, assumption missing column see below. 
   FROM unnest_adgroup ua
     LEFT JOIN taxonomy_category cp ON ua."position" = cp."position"
     LEFT JOIN taxonomy pt ON ua.short_val = pt.short_value AND cp.category = pt.category AND (pt.lob IS NULL OR pt.lob = ua.lob)
         )

    SELECT * 
    from crosstab(
    'select
    cad.account,
    cad.campaign,
    cad.ad_group,
    cad.category,
    cad.full_value
    FROM checked_adgroup cad 
    WHERE  cad.all_correct AND cad.category IS NOT NULL
    --<< above line has 2 errors:
    --<< Incorrectly formatted needs to cad.all_correct is not null AND cad.category IS NOT NULL
    --<< column cad.all_correct does not exist (see missing column above  
    ORDER BY 1,2,3')
    AS final_result( 
     account text, campaign text, ad_group text,
     division text, lob text, match_type text);
```

Now we need to transform the CTE to a second query that crosstab might be ale to use. I have identified each with Postgres $Quoting$, not so much from necessity as standard string quote (') would be sufficant, but more from visibility standing.

```
select * 
   from crosstab(
    $ct1$select
               account,
               campaign,
               ad_group,
               category,
               full_value
         --<< from checked_adgroup cad 
         --<< where cad.all_correct and cad.category is not null
         --<< moved above lines to second query to avoid reference and removed qualification  
         order by 1,2,3
     $ct1$ 
   , $ct2$select * 
            from (
                  select 
                        ua.new_adgroup,
                        ua.account,
                        ua.campaign,
                        ua.ad_group,
                        ua."position",
                        cp.category,
                        pt.full_value,
                        'mssing from orig posted query'  all_correct
                   from unnest_adgroup ua
                   left join taxonomy_category cp on ua."position" = cp."position"
                   left join taxonomy pt on ua.short_val = pt.short_value 
                                        and cp.category = pt.category 
                                        and (pt.lob is null or pt.lob = ua.lob)
                 ) s                    
           where all_correct is not null and cad.category is not null
           --<< move from query1 
       $ct2$ )
  as final_result( 
     account text, campaign text, ad_group text,
     division text, lob text, match_type text  );
```

But at this point I get an error relationship unnest_adgroup does not exist. Which is true as you did not post the definition, not other referenced tables. But that seems to imply the syntax is correct.  
Admittedly, this may be way off base if so, so be it, I can always delete later.   But, I stuck at home with no other projects at the moment and this seems like an interesting question. Looking forward to the results. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to implement this.